# How can I find all files in any matching sub folder groups and copy them to a new directory?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I have a project that constructed of multiple sub projects. As part of that project I have some failure diffs that are generated when snapshot UI tests fail.

The are currently added to a folder alongside the original snapshot.

I'd like to be able to run the test suite and copy any failure snapshots to a single location - this will be happening during CI and enable me to store them as artifacts.

The structure is something like;

```
Project/
    Framework A/
        snapshots/
            failures/
                failure_a_img_1.png
                failure_a_img_2.png
    Framework B/
        snapshots/
            failures/
                failure_b_img_1.png
                failure_b_img_2.png            
                failure_b_img_3.png            
.........
    Framework Z/
        snapshots/
            failures/
                failure_z_img_1.png
                failure_z_img_2.png
```

I'd essentially like to be able to search the entire `Project` folder and copy any files inside a folder group matching `snapshots/failures`

If I run `echo **/*snapshots/failures/*` in the terminal I see all the files/locations.
I tried to construct a command using

```
find . -iname "**/*snapshots/failures/*.png" -type f -exec cp {} ~/desktop \;
```

but there is no output / nothing is copied.

I would appreciate any help with this please.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the directory glob to `find` and pass the filename to `-iname`.

```
find **/*snapshots/failures -iname "*.png" -type f -exec cp {} ~/desktop \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `-path` or `ipath` option for this. Both of these options match given glob pattern again pathname:

```sh
find . -ipath "*/snapshots/failures/*" -type f -exec cp {} ~/desktop \;
```